# Is there a way to display google+ Zagat score on my website?

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to display the Zagat review score that google displays on my site. is there a way to get that data maybe a service that return JSON with the score... thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of the Google Plus API, but you may find what you need as part of the Google Places API: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this - the Google Places API provides user rating 0.0 thru 5.0, but no Zagat ratings.
(Bummer!) 
It does, however, provide a flag (at the end of the spec) that shows if it is a Zagat-recommended establishment.